# When are lvalues moved instead of copied in C++?

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics

Given the following:

```
Foo getFoo()
{
    Foo result = doSomeWork();
    return result;
}
```

- Does C++ guarantee that `result` will be moved, instead of copied? Or to put it another way, is writing `return std::move(result)` superfluous?
- Are there any (other) situations where the standard specifies that a lvalue will be silently moved instead of copied, in the absence of an explicit `std::move` cast?

**Notes:**

- Assume `Foo` is move-constructible.
- Disregarding copy/move elision, which may apply in addition.

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) No. 1) is also misrepresented, since the standard doesn't "guarantee that `result` is moved"; in fact, the entire constructor may be elided. What's true is a much narrower set of rules concerning constructor overload resolution.

Comment: @KerrekSB 2) Yes as well, e.g. throwing an exception may copy-initialize the exception via move-ctor IIRC

Comment: `std::move()` actually inhibits NRVO.

Comment: You didn't ask for this, but the reason why is because it is clear as day that `result` has no further use after that `return` statement. Most other situations are not so obvious, so it would be more difficult for the standard to reason about it.

Comment: Using `std::move(result)` is not recommended because it prevents Return Value Optimization (RVO) from kicking in.

Comment: @PiotrS.: Yes, good point: `throw result` would also work.

Comment: @KerrekSB: so what are the actual rules then? Or could you point me to a certain section of the standard?

Comment: @DanNestor: Sure, it's all in [class.copy], currently 12.8, at the end of the section.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It is guaranteed that `result` is not copied if there is an accessible move constructor.  It may be moved or elided.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: Perhaps not in this toy example, but generally returned objects *can* be used after they are moved-from in the return statement, which sometimes causes problems.  Elision can cause problems as well.

Comment: @PiotrS: No, Standard says "Note:  There cannot be a move from the exception object because it is always an lvalue." in 12.8/31

Comment: @BenVoigt You can't move *from* an exception object. You can move *to* it.

Comment: @T.C. I don't see any special rules for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Despite the fact that the move might be elided, Yes. A copy will never happen if a move constructor is available. I'll quote the paragraph again for clarity. [class.copy]/32:

   > **When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met**, but
   >   not for an *exception-declaration*, **and the object to be copied is
   >   designated by an lvalue, or when the expression in a `return`
   >   statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an
   >   object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or
   >   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*,** **overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an
   >   rvalue**.   If the first overload resolution fails or was not
   >   performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected
   >   constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object’s type (possibly
   >   cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the
   >   object as an lvalue. [*Note:* This two-stage overload resolution must
   >   be performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It
   >   determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed,
   >   and the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is
   >   elided. *— end note* ]

   Applying `std::move` is not superfluous but actually **prevents** copy elision from being performed, [class.copy]/31:

   > — in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when
   >   the expression is **the name of a non-volatile automatic object** [..]
2. Yes, one situation - Again I assume you meant that if copy elision isn't performed, a move is done (Copy elision must be applicable if the lvalue is moved, s.a.).
   Consider this:

   ```
   A a;
   throw a;
   ```

   The criteria are met:

   > — in a *throw-expression*, when the operand is the name of a
   >   non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause
   >   parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost
   >   enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from
   >   the operand to the exception object (15.1) can be omitted by
   >   constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object

   [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a0f51e88400f458).
   This is the only other case where an lvalue is moved instead of copied; The other two cases for copy elision solely include temporaries not bound to a reference (which must therefore be designated by prvalues) and the exception-declaration thingy, which is uninteresting here as it covers the exception object we don't see.

Comment: Note that `std::move` is needed when the types differ, e.g., the function returns `std::unique_ptr<Base>` but the variable you are returning has type `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of return value optimization.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization
The compiler will not copy or move the object at all but identify it.
So, no, I would not write `return std::move(result)` it may even keep the compiler from optimizing.