# throw calling move constructor even for lvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, throw, value-categories

I have the following situation:

```
#include <iostream>

struct T {
    T() {
        std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
    }
    T (const T& t) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }
    T (T&& t) {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
};
void g() {
    T t;
    throw t;
}
void h() {
    static T t;
    throw t;
}

int main(){
    try {
        g();
    } catch(T& t) {
        std::cout << "cautch" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    try {
        h();
    } catch(T& t) {
        std::cout << "cautch" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output on GCC 9.2 with c++11 flag:

```
default
move
cautch
---
default
copy
cautch
```

In [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) is said that the object resulted from the expression in throw expression is copy-initialized. However, when the expression is rvalue, the move ctor is called. In `h()`, I have a lvalue in the throw expression, but the move ctor is called instead of the copy ctor. Why not copying in this case? I tested with `static` and then, copy ctor is called. Does it, in c++11, have something to do with lifetime?

---

Note that's not a question about copy elision. You can use `-fno-elide-constructors`. The result is the same.

If I have this `f()`:

```
void f() {
    throw T();
}
```

I'm having copy elision, but I believe It's not the case I'm asking...

---

Answer:

> "when the expression in a return statement is a id-expression that
>   names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body,
>   overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first
>   performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue"

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953145/817643) for the standard reference.

Comment: @StoryTeller the linked page does not seem to contain an answer to the question asked here---namely, why the compiler is allowed to use a move instead of a copy.

Comment: @Brian - That standard reference out to be updated for C++17 then. That is the canonical after all.

Comment: @StoryTeller The allowance to use a move rather than a copy has existed since C++11. I think it's fine to either add a new answer there, or re-open this question and answer it here. Or create a canonical question for this specific issue. But the OP's question is currently not resolved.

Comment: @Brian - Fair point. Would you like to add the answer there? It would make it a stronger canonical, which is for the best I think.

Comment: @Brian Looks like we already have one that could be improved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122317/does-an-exception-use-move-semantics-when-thrown-in-c11

Comment: What 'cautch' mean? You meant 'caught'.

Comment: @bloody yes....

Comment: There, that looks like another reasonable target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695528/when-are-lvalues-moved-instead-of-copied-in-c

Comment: This last one is nice. Thank you!